# Java - Run time error when running insert nodes at ascending order

Tags: java, runtime

I'm trying to insert nodes in ascending order however, it is not working.

This is the code from the main program:

```
LinearList lst= new LinearList();
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int x=0; x<10;x++)
    {
        AnyClass ax = new AnyClass(r.nextInt(201));
        lst.insertAscOrder(ax);

    }
        lst.showList();
```

The java.util*; has been imported. This is the code from the LinearList class:

```
public void insertAscOrder(AnyClass obj)
{
    Node newNode = new Node(obj);
    if(head==null) //if list is empty
    {
        head=newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        Node tthis=head;
        Node prev=head;
        while(tthis!=null)
        {
            if(tthis.obj.getKey().compareTo(newNode.obj.getKey())>=0)
            {
                if(tthis==prev)//if first node
                {
                    newNode.next=head;
                    head=newNode;
                }
                else //if you're inserting not before first node
                {
                    newNode.next=tthis;
                    prev.next=newNode;
                }
            }
            else //if key of this< key of newNode
            {
                prev=tthis;
                tthis=tthis.next;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I don't think it's the Random class that's the problem because I've tested it and the loop only iterated twice.

Comment: I think you are missing the case of inserting at the end of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the case of inserting at the end of the list. Try to walk through the code on what happens when you insert `1, 2` (in that order). You never insert `2` as the condition of the *while* loop becomes false.

Also, you must `break` once you have successfully inserted an element.

There can be multiple ways to solve this. Here's one way.

```
while(tthis!=null)
{
    if(tthis.obj.getKey().compareTo(newNode.obj.getKey())>=0)
    {
        if(tthis==prev)//if first node
        {
            newNode.next=head;
            head=newNode;
        }
        else //if you're inserting not before first node
        {
            newNode.next=tthis;
            prev.next=newNode;
        }
        break; //breaking and not further looping
    }
    else //if key of this< key of newNode
    {
        prev=tthis;
        tthis=tthis.next;
    }
}
if (tthis == null) { //This means that we have reached the end of the list without inserting the element
  prev.next = newNode; //Create the link from the last node.
}
```